# File name generator in Sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am using sails to upload image in sails and it generates a filename automatically (`554d69bd-ecda-4df2-936b-be9f8d72e760.jpg`).

Right now I have to upload a `base64` image to the server. The issue is I cannot find any function/way to generate the image name like sails generate when we use their upload function.

The uploading function I am using is as follows:

```
var file = req.file('image');
var ext = file.split(';')[0].match(/jpeg|png|gif/)[0];
var data = file.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
var buffer = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
const filename = ??;
fs.writeFile(
    path.resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/uploads') +
        filename +
        ext,
    buffer
);
```

So is there any way that I can generate the file name like sails does or know the encoding they use so that I can generate it myself.

Comment: I don't know anything about sails, but that filename looks like a hexadecimal encryption (keys: 0-9 / a-f). If that's the case, then you can't just create a random generator yourself as you'd need the seed that your sails is using for the encryption. Otherwise sails would be unable to decrypt it. You can read more about the concept [here](https://www.fourmilab.ch/javascrypt/)

Answer (score 0):

Since sails.js built-in used skipper, you may take a look `https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper#using-reqfileupload` at the options part you able to set the filename. Or also you can use another cdn like firebase storage and build own helpers.